# Security precautions for multitenant apps with handlebars

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

We have a multitennant CMS which currently runs on PHP. For the next version we're looking at moving to Node.js and looking at Handlebars as the view engine.

My understanding is that unless I add helpers, the templates are safe and can't manipulate or access global state. Is this understanding correct?

Aside from XSS, are there any other security issues to consider when allowing users to edit their own HBS templates?